# ngIf with a BehaviorSubject changes the order of elements

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-ng-if, behaviorsubject

I have two BehaviorSubject values in my service like this,

```
public showExportCsvModal = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);
public showDownloadModal = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);
```

And my html code is like this,

```
    <p *ngIf="stateService.showExportCsvModal | async">
        {{'exportModal.severalMinutesToComplete' | translate }}
    </p>
    
    <p *ngIf="stateService.showDownloadModal | async">
        {{ 'exportModal.severalMinutesToCompleteDownload' | translate }}
    </p>

    <p>
        {{'exportModal.downloadTheFinishedFileFrom' | translate }}
    </p>
```

The problem is that the third p tag is showing at the top like this,
[image]

How can I evaluate the ngIf statement so that the first p tag shows first and then the common one? Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you recreate the problem in a stackblitz? This is my mocked up version, which works as expected: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-53w12n?file=src/app/app.component.html

Comment: @KurtHamilton the problem is I am using BehaviorObject from another service, if I use it from the component it behaves as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `{{'exportModal.downloadTheFinishedFileFrom' | translate }}` to each `<p *ngIf>`

```
<p *ngIf="stateService.showExportCsvModal | async">
    {{'exportModal.severalMinutesToComplete' | translate }}
    {{'exportModal.downloadTheFinishedFileFrom' | translate }}
</p>

<p *ngIf="stateService.showDownloadModal | async">
    {{ 'exportModal.severalMinutesToCompleteDownload' | translate }}
    {{'exportModal.downloadTheFinishedFileFrom' | translate }}
</p>
```

Comment: This solved the problem. thank you for your help.